# QTableView no longer showing rows since update to 5.7.1

Tags: pyqt5

I recently updated from PyQt 5.7.0 to 5.7.1 and code that worked correctly prior to the update stopped working correctly. So, either my code was always wrong but PyQt5 allowed it to work, or a bug was introduced in PyQt 5.7.1.

I have a custom table view that inherits from QTableView using a custom model that inherits from QAbstractTableModel. When new rows are added to the model, they are not visible in the table view. In fact, no rows ever become visible. Through some debugging, I have validated that the number of rows is changing as expected in my derived model class.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import PyQt5.Qt

class JobTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent):
        super(JobTableModel, self).__init__()
        assert isinstance(parent, QTableView), "'parent' is not a QTableView object"

        self._parent = parent
        self._data = data
        self._rows = 0

        self._updateModel()
    # end constructor

    def updateRows(self, rows):
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self._rows = rows
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
    # end updateRows

    def _updateModel(self):
        # Only update rows that are visible to the user
        # Note: self._parent is a QTableView
        minRow = self._parent.rowAt(0)
        if minRow >= 0:
            maxRow = self._parent.rowAt(self._parent.height())
            if maxRow < 0: maxRow = self._rows - 1
            for row in range(minRow, maxRow + 1):
                self.dataChanged.emit(self.index(row, 0), self.index(row, self.columnCount(None) - 1))

        QTimer.singleShot(490, self._updateModel)
    # end _updateModel

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return str(section)
        #
    # end headerData

    def rowCount(self, modelIndex):
        return self._rows
    # end rowCount

    def columnCount(self, modelIndex):
        return 8 # always the same number of columns
    # end columnCount

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return None
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole: return '{0}, {1}'.format(index.row(), index.column())
        return None
    # end data

class JobTableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, data, parent):
        super(JobTableView, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setModel(JobTableModel(data, self))
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.setWordWrap(False)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(23)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tv = JobTableView(None, None)
    tv.show()
    tv.model().updateRows(1)
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: There's very little point in reporting potential bugs here, because the maintainer of PyQt5 will never see them. And in any case, you firstly need to test using the latest snapshots of [SIP](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download) and [PyQt5](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5). If the problem persists, send a report to the appropriate [mailing list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/support/lists), along with a small, self-contained test case that replicates the problem.

Comment: As the second sentence suggests, I am not reporting a bug here, I am trying to find out if my coding is at fault, or if there is a bug, in which case I will report it.

Comment: There is clearly either a bug in PyQt5 or in your own code. Either way, you need to firstly test using the latest snapshots and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for nothing. You reiterated what I already said in the second sentence, and additionally I provided nearly all the code necessary to test it on your own. For brevity, I didn't put main which is hardly any code and obvious for people suited to answering this question.

Comment: I reiterated it, because **either way** my advice still stands. Testing using the latest snapshots is standard practice for anyone with experience in debugging PyQt programs. The maintaniner of PyQt is very pro-active, and there is a good chance the issue has already been fixed. The code currently in your question is not sufficient for testing.

Comment: Updated with 6 whopping lines of code and 4 import statements that work perfectly with PyQt5.7 and not PyQt 5.7.1. That sure made it insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the test case using PyQt-5.7, PyQt-5.7.1 and PyQt-5.7.2.dev1701131704 (built with SIP-4.19.1.dev1701101411). The problem is reproducible in PyQt-5.7.1, but not in the other two versions. So, as was suggested in the comments, there is a bug in PyQt-5.7.1 which has already been fixed in the latest snapshots.